# не могу понять в чем проблема. Мне нужно узнать если ли значение в объекте, если есть вернуть true, если нет - false

Tags: javascript, объекты

Вот мой код, в консоли все отрабатывает верно, но на странице всегда `undefined`:

```
function f10(arr, val) {

    let out = document.querySelector(".out-10")

    out.innerHTML = Object.values(arr).includes(val) ? "true" : "false"
    console.log(Object.values(arr).includes(val))
}

document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = () => {
    let a10 = {
        "k": 22,
        "d": 54,
        "m": 22,
    }
    document.querySelector('.out-10').innerHTML = f10(a10, 22);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что массив `a10` заполнится данными только **после клика на кнопку**, а в `innerHTML` данные заполняются **до клика**. Вызывать функцию `f10` и заносить данные в `innerHTML` надо в функции клика

Answer (score 0):

Eсли надо, вот решение)

```
function f10(arr, val) {
    for (key in arr) {
        if (arr[key] == val) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = () => {
    let a10 = {
        "k": 22,
        "d": 54,
        "m": 22,
    }
    document.querySelector('.out-10').innerHTML = f10(a10, 22);
};
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это не решение: замени в своем пример `f10(a10, 22)` на `f10(a10, 54)` и получишь результат `false`, хотя значение присутствует в объекте